# React - Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm getting this error: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined when trying to load of my page.

Here's my code :

```
import resumeDataFr from './data/resumeDataFr'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    resumeDataFr: {}
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.handleLoadResumeData()
  }

  handleLoadResumeData () {
    this.setState({ resumeDataFr: resumeDataFr })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header data={this.state.resumeDataFr.header} />
        <Treatment data={this.state.resumeDataFr.treatment} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default App
```

And one of components I want to use:

```
import React from 'react'

const Treatment = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div id='treatments' className='text-center'>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 section-title'>
          <h2>{data.title}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Treatment
```

Here's my data file :

```
const resumeDataFr = {
  navigation: {
    title: 'T',
    items: {
      item0: 'A',
      ...
    }
  },
  header: {
    title: 'AM',
    paragraph: 'I',
    button: 'B'
  },
  team: {
    ...
  },
  treatment: {
    title: 'Title treatments',
    treatments: {
      treatment0: {
        icon: 'Icon',
        title: 'Title',
        text: 'Text'
      },
      ...
    }
  },
  contact: {
    ...
  }
}

export default resumeDataFr
```

It's working when there is only Header component called, but when I add Treatment component it does not work anymore. I check the state from App and looks like fulfilled :

[image: State from App component]

And this is my depencencies :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  }
```

I cannot figure what I am doing wrong, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are accessing resumeDataFr.treatment

```
<Treatment data={this.state.resumeDataFr.treatment} />
```

On the first render it is undefined, when handleLoadResumeData runs it will have the data.

so when you access it from

```
const Treatment = ({ data }) => {
```

when you say data.title
you call title of an undefined object

You can solve like below

```
<h2>{data?.title}</h2>
```

Or you can do something like below

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    resumeDataFr: null
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.handleLoadResumeData()
  }

  handleLoadResumeData () {
    this.setState({ resumeDataFr: resumeDataFr })
  }

  render () {
    if(this.state.resumeDataFr)
       return null; // or show some loading
    return (
      <div>
        <Header data={this.state.resumeDataFr.header} />
        <Treatment data={this.state.resumeDataFr.treatment} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: So actually this is not really an "issue", this is the correct react's behaviour ?
I'm still learning it so thank you for your help, it solved my issue.

Comment: It is the behavior, basically it will render once and the componentdidmount will fire so your default state value would be rendered so you should handle it, thats the idea

Answer (score 0):

When you do `({ data })` you are deconstructing the input parameter to that function (i.e. getting the data property from that object. I think you might want to do this instead:

```
const Treatment = (data) => {
```

And keep everything else the same (e.g. referencing data.title) or possibly this to use the deconstruction to get the properties you want to use like title:

```
const Treatment = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <div id='treatments' className='text-center'>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 section-title'>
          <h2>{title}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You may also need to have a default state or catch the empty state before that data is loaded but I think what I said above is one of your problems.